# KendoUI and breeze

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-grid, breeze

I am using Kendo grid in which I am binding breeze elements into it

```
query = IncidentRepositoryService.getQueyObject(['Severity', 'eq', 'Normal']);
        IncidentRepositoryService.getEntitiesByQuery(query).then(function(results) {

            for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
                unwrapped.push(results[i]._backingStore);
            }
            $scope.incidentDS.data($scope.grid.data);

        });
```

I had to add the backing store cause when I added the real object I got out of stack exception from kendo. I cannot use the backing store cause I havee define properties on top of the breeze types and I need to bind to them

Answer (score 0):

I know this answer comes a little bit late. But maybe someone still searches for an answer to this question. 
You cannot use the Breeze Entity in a Kendo Grid since it contains circular references. 
You can either use the experimental [Breeze Kendo Datasource](https://github.com/kendo-labs/breeze-kendo) or implement yourself a function which creates an object without circular references:

```
// Converts a breeze entity to a kendo data source item.
// Data properties are written to a new objects. Breeze entity
// is moved to __breezeEntity property.
function toKendoItem(entity) {
    if (entity === null || entity === undefined) {
        return entity;
    }

    var props = entity.entityType.dataProperties,
        obj = {};
    props.forEach(function (prop) {
        obj[prop.name] = entity[prop.name];
    });
    obj.__breezeEntity = entity;
    return obj;
}

query = IncidentRepositoryService.getQueyObject(['Severity', 'eq', 'Normal']);
IncidentRepositoryService.getEntitiesByQuery(query).then(function(results) {
    for (var i = 0; i < results.length; i++) {
        unwrapped.push(toKendoItem(results[i]));
    }
    $scope.incidentDS.data($scope.grid.data);
});
```